# Is there a way to arrange objects into a table (or grid) using Inkscape from comand line?

Tags: python, svg, command-line, inkscape

I like the functionality **Inkscape** has to arrange items into a table (or grid). However, I would like to use it programmatically, i mean toward a script. Indeed, I have several plots in a unique .svg file, let's call it "combined.svg" and i would like something like this:

```
inkscape -z -f combined.svg --verb EditSelectAll --verb DialogArrange ROWS COLS SPACING_X SPACING_Y --verb savefile
```

Where `ROWS`, `COLS`, `SPACING_X` and `SPACING_Y` would be integer parameters.

However, for the best of my knowledge i am not able of passing arguments to verbs neither use it without graphical interface.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've follow @Moini suggestion and I wrote down my own script in order to arrange svg files into a grid of a given number of rows and columns. To achieve my goal, I've used this Python library [svg_stack](https://github.com/astraw/svg_stack). I provide my script below. To use it download the library, add a new python file just in the library directory and copy my script. Using python2.7, install the library ( `python2.7 setup.py install` ) and use it as I explain in the following example:

To layout 4 svg files (f1,f2,f3 and f4) into a table of 2 rows and 2 cols and save it to ft.svg use:

```
  pyhon2.7 name_you_give_to_the_script --rows=2 --cols=2 f1.svg f2.svg f3.svg f4.svg > ft.svg
```

```
from svg_stack import *

def main():
    usage = '''%prog FILE1 [FILE2] [...] [options]

This will concatenate FILE1, FILE2, ... to a new svg file. Also, this will arrange 
the provided elements into a table which given number of rows and columns. 
The table will be populated by rows.

EXAMPLE

To layout 4 svg files (f1,f2,f3 and f4) into a table of 2 rows and 2 cols and save it to ft.svg use:
  %prog --rows=2 --cols=2 f1.svg f2.svg f3.svg f4.svg > ft.svg

'''

    parser = OptionParser(usage, version=VERSION)
    parser.add_option("--rows",type='int',
                      help='number of grid rows (required)')
    parser.add_option("--cols",type='int',
                      help='number of grid cols (required)')
    parser.add_option("--spacing_x",type='str', help='size of margin (in any units, px default)')
    parser.add_option("--spacing_y",type='str', default='0px', help='size of margin (in any units, px default)')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    fnames = args

    if options.spacing_x is not None:
        spacing_x = convert_to_pixels(*get_unit_attr(options.spacing_x))
    else:
        spacing_x = 0

    if options.spacing_y is not None:
        spacing_y = convert_to_pixels(*get_unit_attr(options.spacing_y))
    else:
        spacing_y = 0

    if options.rows is None:
        raise ValueError('You must provide the number of rows that you want in the table')

    if options.cols is None:
        raise ValueError('You must provide the number of cols that you want in the table')

    if len(fnames) != options.rows * options.cols:
        raise ValueError('You must supply as much files as it requires to populate the table')

    doc = Document()
    layout = VBoxLayout()
    for i in range(options.rows):
        layout_row = HBoxLayout()        
        for j in range(options.cols):
            fname = fnames[i * options.cols + j]
            layout_row.addSVG(fname, alignment=AlignCenter)

        layout_row.setSpacing(spacing_x)
        layout.addLayout(layout_row)
        layout.setSpacing(spacing_y)

    if 0:
        fd = open('tmp.svg',mode='w')
    else:
        fd = sys.stdout

    doc.setLayout(layout)
    doc.save(fd)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Pd: I know that there may be more elegant solutions out there but I wasn't able to find one as simple as I wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much, @fraverta! This saved me right now!

Comment: Perhaps good to say - in order to install `svg_stack` and to run this script, I had to do:```cd;
git clone https://github.com/astraw/svg_stack.git;

conda create --name svg_stack;
conda activate svg_stack;
conda install python=2.7;
conda install -c conda-forge ipython;
pip install lxml;

cd svg_stack``` and then you can go!

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible currently with Inkscape 0.92.4.

You can, however, write an Inkscape extension or a script in a language of your choice that can do that, and that you can run from the command line.